# Protecting the name of a macro created worksheet without Trust Access

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet

I have a macro that creates a sheet called "final". I need to stop users editing the sheet name so that my code can still function as it is meant to. I've done some research and come up with the following code. This code works for myself, but the problem is that it requires the user to have trust access to Visual Basic Project selected. I have no way of getting all of my users to do this.

I've used the code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim VBP As Object, VBC As Object, CM As Object
Dim strProcName As String
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Final")

Set VBP = wb.VBProject

strProcName = "Worksheet_SelectionChange"

With wb.VBProject.VBComponents(wb.Worksheets(ws.Name).CodeName).CodeModule
    .InsertLines Line:=.CreateEventProc("Deactivate", "Worksheet") + 1, _
    String:=vbCrLf & _
    "    Me.Name = "NameOfSheet""
End With
```

If I have a sheet that is created in a macro, is there a way for me to lock/always rename the name of the sheet if changed without using a VBProject?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider tagging your "final" sheet with a worksheet-scoped Name, and then identify the sheet according to that:

```
Sub Tester()

    Const NAME_NAME As String = "FINAL_SHEET"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Final")

       .Names.Add Name:=NAME_NAME, RefersToR1C1:="=TRUE"

       .Name = "WasFinal" 'simulates user changing sheet name

       MsgBox GetSheetWithName(NAME_NAME).Name ' "WasFinal" - the correct sheet

    End With

End Sub

Function GetSheetWithName(sName As String, Optional wb As Workbook)
Dim sht As Worksheet, nm As Name, rv As Worksheet
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each sht In wb.Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next
        Set nm = sht.Names(sName)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not nm Is Nothing Then
            Set rv = sht
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sht
    Set GetSheetWithName = rv
End Function
```

Comment: I've just tested this code. From what I can see it changes a sheet called "Final" to "WasFinal". It still allows me to change the sheet name to anything I want e.g "tree". This is what I'm trying to stop (users changing the name of the worksheet).

Comment: I understood your question to mean "how do I keep my code working even if a user changes my sheet name?".  This allows you to do that, by allowing you to identify a specific sheet regardless of its name. My `Tester` code is *just an example* of how you could apply it (i.e. the sheet name change is to mimic user action).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()

Dim SN As String

SN = "Final Sheet"

If Worksheets(1).Name <> SN Then

Worksheets(1).Name = SN

End If


End Sub
```

This code assumes that the worksheet "Final Sheet" is worksheet 1. This code will work if someone changes the name of the sheet, but if they change the order of the sheet, the sheet that is now in `Worksheets(X)` (where X is your index number) will be renamed to "Final Sheet"

Change the `X` in `Worksheets(X).Name` to the index number of your worksheet

**UPDATE**

```
Sub Test()

Dim SN As String

SN = "Final Sheet"

If Final_Sheet.Name <> SN Then

Final_Sheet.Name = SN

End If


End Sub
```

The above code will change the name of the sheet where the codename is equal to "Final_Sheet". So if anyone changes the name of the sheet, it will be changed back when this code is run, regardless of order

Just thought I'd mention that there are ways of stopping the user from renaming the cell (disable right click, double click ect), but why go through the hassle of messing about with that when you can simply run a macro to rename the sheet before your macro runs.

Answer (score -1):

The worksheet object offers several properties to protect worksheet childs like rows or columns or cells from user changes.

As I understood your question, you want to  protect the worksheet itself from renaming.

So you have to change a Workbook property (parent of worksheet) to protect the worksheets from user changes.

By the following 2 simple subs you can protect/unprotect your workbook:

```
Sub protectWb()
Dim testWb As Workbook
Set testWb = ActiveWorkbook
testWb.Protect
End Sub

Sub unprotectWb()
Dim testWb As Workbook
Set testWb = ActiveWorkbook
testWb.Unprotect
End Sub
```

or even more simple:

1. open the workbook you want to protect
2. open VBA Editor by hitting `ALT+F11`
3. type `Activeworkbook.protect` in the direct-window of VBE

Advantage: You don't need to put the VBA code into the workbook itself.

Disadvantage: You will protect ***all*** worksheets of the workbook and can not protect just one of them and keep the others open.

What I don't know (means you may have to try): Is the user still allowed to do the things you want the user to do with this protection ?